# Can While Loop be used for Error Catching?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, while-loop

I am using try catch algorithm when inserting a record to a MySQL table. My scripting language is PHP.

```
try {
 /*
 UDID generation algo goes here.
 */
$sql = "INSERT INTO tablex (udid, name)
VALUES ('$udid', 'Doe')";

$conn->exec($sql);
echo "New record created";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Error"
}

$conn = null;
```

How do I re-write the above so that instead of try catch, I use a loop. If there is an error, try again. Break out of the loop if there is no error.

There is "While True" but I don't know if the "Try Catch" should be part of the While True loop..

The purpose of this is to save a UDID - the unique value is set in MYSQL. If I generate the same value, I may get the error. Hence, why the loop.

Comment: I don't use PHP, but a very intriguing question!

Comment: Exceptions shouldn't be used for control flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you're going about this the wrong way. Instead of trying to insert a value that might not be unique, I would try to see if that value exists first. You could perform a query such as

```
do {
   //$udid = create uuid

   $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablex WHERE udid = :udid";
   $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
   $statement->bindValue("udid", $udid);
   $result = $statement->fetchAll();
} while ($result["count"] === 1);

//insert row into table
```

This is just off the top of my head and it can be refactored even better. You could also leverage your database to generate the UDID for you if you prefer. You could run a query to get all of the udid's from your table and just run in_array to check to see if the value is there, then you're only hitting your database twice. Anyway, you really don't want to try to abuse a try catch like that.

Answer (score 0):

mysql has a function for something like this you would add an "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" to your insert statement
Example:

```
INSERT INTO table(x, y, z) values (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE x=?;
```

Also see this link for more info:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html